# How to get all points for a fitted spline in R?

Tags: r, regression, splines

I am trying to find the MSE of a fitted `smooth.spline` in `R` (and compare it with other methods) using a default data set (cars). But using `predict` function decreases the number of my data points. In other words, I have 50 pairs of data points (x,y) but `predict` function gives me 35 points (yhatsp). How can I get all 50 points for my spline?
Thanks

> library(datasets)
>
> x=cars[,2]
>
> y=cars[,1]
>
> yhatsp=predict(smooth.spline(x,y))$y
>
> MSE=mean((y-yhatsp)^2)

Comment: See argument `newdata` in `predict`. You can specify at which points predictions are calculated.

Comment: better question for stack overflow?

Comment: @rbatt : Sorry, I am not very familiar with differences between these sites. Anyway, my problem is solved if you think is not appropriate for here I can delete it.

Comment: O, I see -- you posted your own answer which you cannot yet accept.   Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Roman Luštrik :
adding `newdata` solved my problem:

> library(datasets)
>
> x=cars[,2]
>
> y=cars[,1]
>
> yhatsp=predict(smooth.spline(x,y),x)$y
>
> MSE=mean((y-yhatsp)^2)